# rails: fields_for and collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fields-for

i would like to use an additional collection for a fields_for. this collection should hold all the possibilities to be used in fields_for.

Lets say I have a person with tasks that will happen regularly each week on the same day. In the person form, i should have an entry for each day, even if there are not yet any saved tasks. I tried:

```
<% form_for(@person) do |f| %>
...

  <% f.fields_for :tasks, @weekdays do |task_fields| %> 
    <%= weekday.name %>: 
    <%= project_fields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

now there should be for each weekday a text field to enter the name of the task of that day. for example weekday.name = "monday" and task.name = "drinking coffee", task.weekday_id = 1

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Are you getting some error you don't understand? If you're asking how to implement something perhaps you can be more specific or provide some clarification.

Comment: Have you actually populated @weekdays with the default, starting data that you describe?

Comment: Two things, one `weekday` does not look like it would have a value, you can use `task_fields.object.name`, two I think the docs are wrong and you can't pass a collection as the second parameter to `fields_for`. Investigating...

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating through the week_days. You should do like this:

```
<% @weekdays.each_with_index do |weekday, i| %>
  <% f.fields_for :tasks do |task_fields| %> 
    <%= weekday.name %>: 
    <%= task_fields.text_field :name %>
    <%= task_fields.hidden_field :weekday_id, :value => (i + 1) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you have a table 'weekdays', then hidden_field value should be `weekday.id`

**Edit: July 30**

I think I completely messed up this answer. Let me try to improve it.

```
<% f.fields_for :tasks, @weekdays do |task_fields| %> 
  <%= weekday = task_fields.object %>
  <%= weekday.name %>: 
  <%= task_fields.text_field :name %>
  <%= task_fields.hidden_field :weekday_id, :value => weekday.id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Note that according to the docs, it should be possible to specify a collection as the second argument to `fields_for` as the OP was trying to do.  In my experience, that seems to be broken though.  Attempting to use a helper such as `foo_fields.text_field :name` results in an exception something like `undefined method 'name' for #<Array:0xb6ed329c>`

Comment: Slightly incorrect. A) as mentioned directly above, rails supports a second parameter that defines the collection to be iterated through and B) more importantly, using that will ensure the HTML attribute names are generated with the `id` of each child object when using form elements like radio buttons and such (e.g. `person[tasks][1][:field_name]`).

And one last thing, not directly related to this question but relevent. Be sure to include `accepts_nested_attributes_for :<children>` in the parent model. Otherwise it won't fail in an obvious way but you will be left pulling your hair out.

Comment: To be honest I think I completely missed the point of the question in this answer and was terribly wrong :D